# Ubuntu 13.04 - How do you make selected terminal tab more prominent?

Tags: ubuntu

I using ctrl + page up or page down to cycle through my tabs, however it is very difficult to distinguish which tab I am on since terminal windows look really similar. Is there a way to set the color of the selected tab or something?

Comment: I hate this problem too. In KDE, I change the "Widget Style" to "Cleanlooks" which has a blue bar on the selected tab. I don't know the answer for gnome or whatever Ubuntu 13 has.